# How to handle FCM notification in Jetpack compose with Navigation graph

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-jetpack-compose

When app is in background and user clicks on a notification, what would be the preferred way to handle data sent in notification?

For instance, I have an order ID: 12345 and when I receive that order status has been changed, I want to click on a notification and navigate to the order.

I am using jetpack compose without fragments.

It's simple to navigate from local notification, by using PendingIntent but how to do that with FCM notification in system tray?

Thanks!

Comment: According to our live project implementation(taking example of your case), we just add orderId as extras in intent and context of base activity in PendingIntent, then from BaseActivity, we navigate to Order Screen through navController and passing orderId as argument in it